# NSRegularExpression splitting / reparsing a match

Tags: swift, regex, regex-group, nsregularexpression

I'm making a regex for chess notation and there's one particular part that's almost impossible to parse in 1 pass...

Notation can look like this

`5.Nd5e3`

This means: Move 5, White moved Knight to coordinate `d5`, Black moved Pawn to `e3`

Much like SVG or something like that it's as succinct as possible, and you omit the P from pawn moves.

However, if in this case there are multiple Knights that can move to `d5` you specify which knight moved, either by rank, file or both. Meaning `Nd5e3` could also mean, Moved Knight on `d5` to `e3`.

So the regex per move would look something like this

`\([KQNBR])?\([a-h]?[1-8]?)([a-h][1-8])`

Piece?, Piece's start rank? and/or file?, Piece's end rank and file.

There's no way to tell except to say

- I'm expecting a pair of moves for all except maybe the last move
- Because of the above, it would be `5.Nd5e3e3`
  (This isn't valid piece-wise but just saying, you'd get more notation unless the player playing as black resigned after that move)
- For all notation, the matches splitting that results in 2 matches is likely to be correct for all except the last pair.

I'm looking for an elegant way to run over these strings and get the white and black move out and not just 1 move.

My only idea currently would be to get the coordinates out first, then check the previous characters for the piece notation / lack of, but I'm a regex noob and I'm hoping there's a nice way to grab them, especially in iOS / Swift.

Comment: Maybe you can do this with NSScanner instead?

Comment: I’m no expert but your current regex will not match the opposite move, that is white moves a pawn and black moves a knight? And no support for captures check mate or check, or is this intentional? I have no solution for this but maybe an approach could be to have 2 or 3 regex to keep them less complicated and try them one after another until you have a match.

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson it would actually match how I'd like, because the N would separate the 2 moves. `e3Nd5` would because `e3` and `Nd5` the issue only arises if the first move and a Piece notation and the second move is a pawn move.

Comment: Maybe you could get some information out by checking the length of the string in determining what type of regex to use.

Comment: Yeah I think that's the only way... as I'm expecting 2 if I don't get a pair of moves I can run over the coordinates and find the moves with surrounding elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think is possible in a single expression. I'm no chess player so I read the [Disambiguating moves section in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)#Disambiguating_moves) just to understand.

The following regular expression uses named capture groups but it's not a requirement just a convinience.

```
(?<Piece>[KQNBR])(?<StartingFile>[a-h]{0,1})(?<StartingRank>[1-8]{0,1})(?<Destination>[a-h][1-8])
```

I tested it using this [site](https://regex101.com). The three possible scenarios as I read in wiki:

- Qh4e1

[image]

- Rdf8

[image]

- R1a3

[image]

And the simple scenario when no disambiguation is needed works as well:

[image]

I think all possibilities are covered with tis expression.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, the named capture groups could be really useful for me in the future.. however it doesn't solve the problem. Applying my problem to your example. `Qh4e1` should be 2 matches. `Qh4` group piece Q and group destination `h4` and group destination `e1` because there are 2 moves in a pair.